# Is this CASE expression in a COALESCE function redundant?

Tags: sql, postgresql

While examining a previously written query, I came across the following:

```
coalesce(
        min( CASE WHEN plo.transaction_type IS DISTINCT FROM 'QRec' THEN plo.id END ),
        min( plo.id )
    )
```

It looks to me as if this is functionally equivalent to just `min( plo.id )`. Is there some subtlety I'm missing? Some edge case in which they won't produce identical results? In other words: is there any reason I shouldn't just replace it with `min( plo.id )`?

If it matters, I'm working in PostgreSQL 9.3, but since coalesce, min, and case are all ANSI, a generic 'sql' tag seemed more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same.  If `plo.transaction_type` only takes on the value `'QRec'`, then the first expression returns `NULL`.

These would also return different results if the actual minimum were only on `'QRec'` rows.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out. The distinction is that the CASE is inside the min() function (as opposed to the min() function being inside the CASE).

So the first parameter in the `coalesce()` function gives the minimum `plo.id` value among all rows that have a non-`'Qrec'` `transaction_type`, whereas the second parameter gives the minimum `plo.id` value over *all* rows, regardless of `transaction_type`.